# forest trees, boxes and arrow

Tags: linguistics, forest

I am trying to learn `forest`, but I am having some problems with it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{%
 pretty nice empty nodes/.style={
 for tree={
  calign=fixed edge angles,
  parent anchor=children,
  delay={if content={}{
      inner sep=0pt,
      edge path={\noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- (.children)\forestoption{edge label};}
    }{}}
  },
 }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
 [, pretty nice empty nodes
    [
        [X,name=x] 
        [Y,l=5mm,circle,dotted,draw,name=y] {\node[draw,fit=(y) (!us),rotate=135] {};}
    ] 
    [Z]
 ]
 \draw[->,dotted, thick] (y) to [out=south,in=south] (x); 
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What I want to do is:
1) reduce the height of the box including Z and Y;
2) the thick non-dotted arrow should start from the bottom of the box.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Your example doesn't compile, and produces lots of errors.  So you should fix those errors first or ask about the errors specifically.

Comment: It should work now.

Comment: What do you mean by `too high` exactly? What should it look like?

Comment: By the way, isn't it rude not to attribute code you've got from others?

Comment: @cfr: what do you mean? what code?

Comment: I just need to put the nodes Y and Z in a rectangle, and be able to draw an arrow starting from the bottom of that box.

Comment: I meant `pretty nice empty nodes`. Either you just happened to define an identically named style to that posted by somebody else, or you got it from the somebody else. (I should say that I cannot remember who wrote it, but somebody here did. Possibly me. Possibly somebody else.)

Comment: oh! I'm sorry, yes - I asked a question about it sometime ago, and I have been using it in my document. I forgot to post credits, sorry.

Comment: @cfr I think `pretty nice empty nodes` is yours and mine was `fairly nice empty nodes`. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: boxed nodes with arrow from base]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{%
  pretty nice empty nodes/.style={
    for tree={
      calign=fixed edge angles,
      parent anchor=children,
      delay={
        if content={}{
          inner sep=0pt,
          edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) -- (.children)}
        }{},
      },
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={circle}
  [, pretty nice empty nodes
    [
        [X, name=x]
        [Y, l=5mm, circle, dotted, draw, name=y]
        {
          \draw [red] (y.west) -- (!us.north) -- (!us.east) -- (y.south) -- cycle ;
        }
    ]
    [Z]
 ]
 \draw[->,dotted, thick] (y) to [out=south,in=south] (x);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks @cfr! how can I now name the box, so that I can draw an arrow starting from it?

Comment: @RobertP. There's already an arrow starting from it. But you can use the corners of the box by adding `coordinate (A)` or whatever after the relevant point e.g. `(!us.north) coordinate (top)`. You can't name the box as a whole because it is a path and not a node. (Actually, paths can be named, but it wouldn't be useful here.)